# Exclude Content Source from Everything

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, search-results

I defined a new Content Source called "Competitor Websites" containing a few website addresses of our competitors. I don't want these websites to be shown under "Everything". So i tried to exlude this Content Source via Query Transformation like

```
{searchTerms} NOT ContentSource:"Competitor Websites"
{searchTerms} ContentSource<>"Competitor Websites"
{searchTerms} NOT ContentSource="Competitor Websites"
```

but none of them worked. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you would have got answer for this by now.  Did you try using following filter:

{searchTerms} -ContentSource:"Competitior Website"